# trouble using extern .world

Tags: ros, gazebo, world, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I'm currently working with [this great package (rrt_exploration)](http://wiki.ros.org/rrt_exploration) and i'm trying to use different map to simulate my environment on gazebo.
I tested the map including in the package, and also some map from gazebo package (as willow garage).

Currently i'm trying to use [these worlds](http://data.nvision2.eecs.yorku.ca/3DGEMS/) on the package but it doesn't work.

My guess is that there is different type of .world : for instance  here is the code of one of the working world :

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<sdf version="1.4">
 <world name="default">
<include>
  <uri>model://ground_plane</uri>
</include>
<include>
  <uri>model://sun</uri>
</include>


<model name="floor">
   <pose>0 0 -0.110060  0 0 0</pose>
  <static>false</static>
  <link name="floorPlan">
    <visual name="visual">
      <geometry>
        <mesh><uri>file://largeMap.dae</uri></mesh>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
  
  
    <collision name="collision">
      <geometry>
        <mesh><uri>file://largeMap.dae</uri></mesh>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
</model>
</world>
</sdf>
```

and here is (a part of) the .world i'm trying to use :

```
<sdf version='1.6'>
<world name='default'>
<scene>
  <shadows>0</shadows>
  <ambient>0.4 0.4 0.4 1</ambient>
  <background>0.7 0.7 0.7 1</background>
</scene>
<light name='sun' type='directional'>
  <cast_shadows>0</cast_shadows>
  <pose frame=''>0 0 5 0 -0 0</pose>
  <diffuse>0.8 0.8 0.8 1</diffuse>
  <specular>0.1 0.1 0.1 1</specular>
  <attenuation>
    <range>1000</range>
    <constant>0.9</constant>
    <linear>0.01</linear>
    <quadratic>0.001</quadratic>
  </attenuation>
  <direction>-0.5 0.5 -1</direction>
</light>
<physics name='default_physics' default='0' type='ode'>
  <max_step_size>0.001</max_step_size>
  <real_time_factor>1</real_time_factor>
  <real_time_update_rate>1000</real_time_update_rate>
</physics>
<scene>
  <ambient>0.4 0.4 0.4 1</ambient>
  <background>0.7 0.7 0.7 1</background>
  <shadows>1</shadows>
</scene>
<spherical_coordinates>
  <surface_model>EARTH_WGS84</surface_model>
  <latitude_deg>0</latitude_deg>
  <longitude_deg>0</longitude_deg>
  <elevation>0</elevation>
  <heading_deg>0</heading_deg>
</spherical_coordinates>
<model name='ground_plane'>
  <static>1</static>
  <link name='link'>
    <collision name='collision'>
      <geometry>
        <plane>
          <normal>0 0 1</normal>
          <size>100 100</size>
        </plane>
      </geometry>
      <surface>
        <friction>
          <ode>
            <mu>1</mu>
            <mu2>1</mu2>
          </ode>
          <torsional>
            <ode/>
          </torsional>
        </friction>
        <bounce/>
        <contact>
          <ode/>
        </contact>
      </surface>
      <max_contacts>10</max_contacts>
    </collision>
    <visual name='visual'>
      <cast_shadows>0</cast_shadows>
      <geometry>
        <plane>
          <normal>0 0 1</normal>
          <size>100 100</size>
        </plane>
      </geometry>
      <material>
```

(not the complete code : it's about 38903 lines...

My question is : what's the difference between these two files .world, and how can i use the second  one on my simulation ?

Thanks in advance !

EDIT : it seems to be a compatibility problem :

```
    Warning [parser.cc:340] Converting a deprecated source[/home/lklk/hugo_ws/src/rrt_exploration_tutorials/launch/includes/worlds/office_earthquake.world].
Warning [Converter.cc:59]   Version[1.6] to Version[1.4]
  Please use the gzsdf tool to update your SDF files.
    $ gzsdf convert [sdf_file]
Error [Converter.cc:127] Unable to convert from SDF version 1.6 to 1.4
Warning [parser.cc:478] XML Attribute[frame] in element[pose] not defined in SDF, ignoring.
Warning [parser.cc:478] XML Attribute[name] in element[physics] not defined in SDF, ignoring.
Warning [parser.cc:478] XML Attribute[default] in element[physics] not defined in SDF, ignoring.
Error [parser.cc:697] XML Element[torsional], child of element[friction] not defined in SDF. Ignoring.[friction]
Error [parser.cc:688] Error reading element <friction>
Error [parser.cc:688] Error reading element <surface>
Error [parser.cc:688] Error reading element <collision>
Error [parser.cc:688] Error reading element <link>
Error [parser.cc:688] Error reading element <model>
Error [parser.cc:688] Error reading element <world>
Error [parser.cc:348] Unable to read element <sdf>
Error:   Could not find the 'robot' element in the xml file
         at line 81 in /build/buildd/urdfdom-0.2.10+dfsg/urdf_parser/src/model.cpp
Error [parser_urdf.cc:2608] Unable to call parseURDF on robot model
Error [parser.cc:273] parse as old deprecated model file failed.
Error [Server.cc:300] Unable to read sdf file[/home/assystem/hugo_ws/src/rrt_exploration_tutorials/launch/includes/worlds/office_earthquake.world]

Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
Msg Publicized address: 172.28.35.141
gzserver: /usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/recursive_mutex.hpp:101: boost::recursive_mutex::~recursive_mutex(): Assertion `!pthread_mutex_destroy(&m)' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
[gazebo-2] process has died [pid 7719, exit code 134, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/gazebo_ros/gzserver -e ode /home/assystem/hugo_ws/src/rrt_exploration_tutorials/launch/includes/worlds/office_earthquake.world __name:=gazebo __log:=/home/assystem/.ros/log/946c34f6-1bd8-11e8-afd1-2c27d72db473/gazebo-2.log].
log file: /home/assystem/.ros/log/946c34f6-1bd8-11e8-afd1-2c27d72db473/gazebo-2*.log
Warning [gazebo.cc:215] Waited 1seconds for namespaces.
Warning [gazebo.cc:215] Waited 1seconds for namespaces.
Warning [gazebo.cc:215] Waited 1seconds for namespaces.
Warning [gazebo.cc:215] Waited 1seconds for namespaces.
Warning [gazebo.cc:215] Waited 1seconds for namespaces.
Warning [gazebo.cc:215] Waited 1seconds for namespaces.
```

Thus what should i do to be able to use a SDF 1.4 ? what do i have to upgrade ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283415/trouble-using-extern-.world/) by [StanSmooth](https://answers.ros.org/users/32748/stansmooth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2018-02-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-23**:
The most obvious difference is that the first file seems to be SDF `v1.4` and the second one `v1.6`. SDF is the format Gazebo uses to describe [simulation environments](http://sdformat.org/). There is a great deal of bw-compatibility in SDF, but forward compatibility might not be possible. ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-23**:
.. you'll have to check whether the Gazebo version you're using is capable of loading `v1.6` worlds.

You don't describe what "is not working", so this is the best we can do at the moment.

**Comment by [StanSmooth](https://answers.ros.org/users/32748/stansmooth/) on 2018-02-27**:
yes sorry, i edited my previous post. As you said, it's due to compatibilities errors.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-27**:
Any reason you cannot use Gazebo 7? That is installable on Ubuntu Trusty/ROS Indigo and would get you SDF 1.6 support.

**Comment by [StanSmooth](https://answers.ros.org/users/32748/stansmooth/) on 2018-02-28**:
Yes, the package i want to use seems not to be compatible with gazebo 7

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-28**:
Then you seem to be forced to adapt the `world` file to a lower version of the format. That might mean that certain features will not be available / work.

**Comment by [hasauino](https://answers.ros.org/users/26499/hasauino/) on 2018-03-02**:
hello StanSmooth,
gazebo simulation files in the "rrt_exploration_tutorials" package are for Gazebo 7. So it should work.
I will try to use on te world files you are trying to launch and see what the problem is..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello StanSmooth,
I'm not sure about the compatibly issue, I don't believe it's the problem. Because the Gazebo files in the rrt_exploration_tutorials package are for Gazebo 7. (I tested them on ROS indigo with Gazebo 2 and ROS kinect with Gazebo 7).

> what's the difference between these two files

The first (short one) file only defines one model, which is named "floor", and it only defines some properties like "collision" and "visual". So it only has one model.

The second one, is the same except it has more models defined (I saw the complete file) and it also defines other things like lighting and so on.

> how can i use the second one on my simulation ?

If you look at one of the .world files provided, for exmaple this one: "simple_env_1.world", you will see it needs certain files on your computer. For example, in Line 151:

model://book_orange/meshes/book_cover.dae

This file "book_cover.dae" should be on your computer.

Those files are provided, but you have to download them and put them in the right place.

---

Originally posted by [hasauino](https://answers.ros.org/users/26499/hasauino/) with karma: 91 on 2018-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1